# Why does the latency of a request-response message pair reduce when increasing rate of messages sent over TCP?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, network-programming, low-latency

### Intro

I have a setup of a client and a server communicating over a TCP connection, and I experience weird latency-behaviour which I cant understand.

### Context

The client sends a request message to the server, which responds with a response message to client.
I define **latency** as the time from sending a request message to receipt of a response message. I can send request messages at different **rates** (throttling the frequency of requests), however I always have at most one outstanding request message at any time. I.e, **no concurrent/overlapping request-response message pairs**.

I have implemented the sending of request and response message in three ways: first is directly on TCP sockets with my own serialization method etc, second is using gRPC for the communication over RPC using HTTP2, third is using Apache Thrift (an RPC framework similar to gRPC).
gRPC is in turn implemented in 4 different client/server types, and for Thrift I have 3 different client/server types.

In all solutions, I experience a decrease in latency when increasing the sending rate of request messages (In gRPC and Thrift a request-response pair is communicated via an RPC method).
The best latency is observed when not throttling the request rate at all, but sending a new request as soon as a response is received.
Latency is measured using the std::chrono::steady_clock primitive.
I have no idea what's causing this. I make sure to warmup the TCP connection (passing TCP slow start phase) by sending 10k request messages before starting the real testing.

How I implement the throttling and measure latency (on client ofc):

```cpp
double rate;
std::cout << "Enter rate (requests/second):" << std::endl;
std::cin >> rate;
auto interval = std::chrono::microseconds(1000000)/rate;

//warmup-phase is here, but not included in this code.

auto total_lat = std::chrono::microseconds(0);
auto iter_time = start_time;
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++){ // send 10k requests.
  iter_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  RequestType request("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
  ResponseType response;
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  sendRequest(request); //these looks different depending on gRPC/Thrift/"TCP"
  receiveResponse(&response);
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
  total_lat+=dur;
  std::this_thread::sleep_until(iter_time+interval); //throttle the sending..
}
// mean latency: total_lat / i
```

I run the client/server in separate docker containers using docker-compose, and I also run them in kubernetes cluster. In both cases I experience the same behaviour. I am thinking maybe my throttling/time measureing code is doing stuff that I dont know about/understand.

The TCP sockets are set to TCP_NODELAY in all cases.
The servers are single/multithreaded nonblocking/blocking, all kinds of different variations, and the clients are some synchronous, some asynchronous etc. So a lot of variation however the same behavious across them all.

Any ideas out here to what could cause such behaviour?

Comment: My two cents: From your description it appears you reach a congestion window size where there is no congestion event happening (yet), or recovery via duplicate fast retransmits is quick because you wait for each response, or equilibrium is attained because of window size limiting factors. This also affects the sender on the remote side in a similar way. Slower sends, slower linear growth of remote congestion window size per response, since you are already past slow_start aggressive growth.

Comment: @DNT Thanks for the input!
By what you write first, regarding the congestion window size; do you mean that my congestion window grows slower when sending less frequent requests compared to more frequent requests, and thus a slower requests get more impacted by ACKs?

Comment: Rasmus Johanson: It is hard to say without doing actual measurements and checking all local environmental factors. Congestion window grows linearly after slow_start and this rate stops when a congestion or loss event happens and is rectified by algorithms within the stack such as fast retransmit. As the window grows, more data can be sent out until size limits are reached or an adverse event happens in which case we have exponential reduction up to initial size which depends on implementation defaults and parameters. What Liam Kelly points out can also be a factor in the case you describe

Comment: Aside: For some reason SO does not want to add an at sign before your name :)

Comment: @DNT Thank you for your time and input :) I have taken some data communication and computer networking courses, but have limited practical experience :)

Comment: @RasmusJohansson *(cit.)* '… **real-time assurances** in c++ code and/or how to "set it in the container"?'~Wish being a candidate for an Oxymoron Of the Year :o) Could hardly imagine a stronger contradiction. A wish to have some **warrants "inside"** a sandbox, that is then put inside a latency+indeterminism-rich ecosystem (Docker re-wrapper of real-toys into software emulated (Who manages the priorities there? Where? Inside? Of the abstracted, software-controlled wrapper itself? Of the external intra-wrapper-domain(s)? Kubernetes?) **If indeed serious into a RealTime-system design Not this**

Comment: @DNT ~ the @-convention, try not to type the name and add @ sign later, start from @-sign and type first few, even lowecased chars of the displayed name ( sometimes this does not auto-recognise a user, so may snoop with a mouse over a user-name URL, to see the orignal user-name as was first registered by the O/S systems and perhaps later re-edited ( browsers show URL in some preview, maybe in lower-left or similar preview location, as you perhaps routinely use already ), so try a few chars from that "name" after the @-sign to help the auto-recogniser assist you. Even that not work?… :o) Life…

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks, I think I tried all possible permutations, but in the post the name was cut in half using only the second part 'Johansson'

Comment: @DNT Excuse me if 've missed your point: I just started to type @r and the auto-recogniser started with the left-top field above the comment-edit frame, bering a click-able advice to auto-fill RasmusJohanson ( which after a click gets re-filled into the comment-field ). This auto-advice stops working after a first @-referral, similarly the text analysis often  gets confused whence there is not a white-space between the first few chars and the rest of the text-field (A poor regex design, isn't it? :o) ) So not all auto-advice cases get served well. In troubles move cursor to the start of text

Answer (score 1):

Right now I think the latency issue is not in the network stack, but the rate in which you are generating and receive messages.

Your test code does not appear to have any real-time assurances, which also need to be set in the container. This means that your 'for loop' does not run at the same speed every time. The OS scheduler can stop it to run other processes (this is how processes share the CPU). This behavior can get even more complicated with containerization mechanisms.

While there are mechanisms in TCP which can cause latency variations (as mentioned by @DNT), I don't think you would be seeing them. Especially if the server and client are local. This is why I would rule out the rate of message generation  and reception first before looking at the TCP stack.

Comment: Thanks for input. How would the rate affect the scheduling between `start()` and `end()` in `while(1){start(); send(); receive(); end(); sleep_to_keep_rate();}` Does the OS prioritize the thread lower if I run with slower rate, meaning that I sleep a lot of the time. Would in that case a busy-wait loop be better to make the high-rate och low-rate cases behave more similar? Hope I made myself clear..

Comment: Darn 5 minutes limitation in editing comments...
What I mean is to replace the `sleep_to_keep_rate()` with a busy wait loop instead

Comment: Do you have some references or links to real-time assurances in c++ code and/or how to "set it in the container"? :)

Comment: @RasmusJohansson here is an example of a program setting schedule priority; however, the OS still needs to give permission for it to use it and to get it work in a container requires much more information (cgroup retrictions and docker settings). https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/APS33DTE/DOCU_003.HTM

Comment: After looking some more at my issue, I really cannot see how the rate of sending messages would impact the latency between sending and receiving a message, as I'm not sending a new message until a response to the previous message has been received.
Essentially, why would `send();receive();sleep(10);send();receive();` result in a larger latency between send() and receive() then say, `send();receive();sleep(1);send();receive();` (blocking receive() ofc)

Comment: Firstly, I think you screwed up your example because 10s > 1s so of course its a longer delay. Secondly this is a very complicated subject, so here is it boiled down greatly: there are two 'spaces' on an OS: Userspace and kernel space. Your program runs in Userspace till: 1) the OS scheduler puts it to sleep so another proc can get time 2) your program needs something from kernelspace (socket data, sleep(), etc). Both these cases inject variable delays, so even `sleep(10)` will not give you exactly 10 sec of sleep and recv/send will also not be consistent especially in blocking mode.